# Android: Activity Host?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a basic problem but Google is not yielding many results for me (well not english ones anyways). Basically all I want to do is this:

I have a graphic I need to use as a persistent header across the App, as in: I cant have it slide off the screen on new intent calls even if it just comes back in the new view, the client will complain hardcore because the iPhone version of this App doesn't do that.

So basically I'm thinking of something like how TabHost works but without tabs. Is there a way to create a new Layout File to be loaded as the main with a LinearLayout in it, have the graphic up top, and then nest an "intent" or "activity" in another element in the layout file?

Google probably isn't yielding me any results because I'm probably using the wrong terminology here, but any help on this matter would be incredible!

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm sorry i should mention that this needs to be 2.3.3 (Gingerbread) compatible. I'm hearing about "Fragments" and I see they got introduced in ADK3 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Framgent or Fragment compatiblibity package will work for you . even no need to search on google because Fragment Example of ApiDemoes will be enough to get idea .

Main Activity should have 1 Header View and one Fragment Placeholder  . then push, pop fragments in this place holder .

One more Way hitting  to my head is :

Create a `TabWidget` with 1 tab . its view will be static header and add an activity group to content . now moving portion fo screen will be child of an `ActivityGroup` .

Comment: Will this work for Gingerbread though? The docs are very scrupulous in informing me that it was introduced in 3 and requires API level 11 (I'm working with 10)

Comment: Okay i got the compatability package v13, going to go ahead and give this a shot! Seems to be taking me in the correct direction, so I'll definitely upvote now, I'll mark as answer when this thing works :)

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the `windowBackground` attribute for your activities might work for you. Basically you create a style (usually in a `res/values/themes.xml` file) like this:

```
<style name="WithPersistentHeader" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/persistent_header</item>
</style>
```

You can then apply the style to your whole `<application>` or on a per `<activity>` basis in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/WithPersistentHeader" >

    <!-- activities and services ... -->

</application>
```

Each of your activity layout will then need to vacant the space where the header is located so it can show through from the window underneath.

There's not much documentation about this, but there's an [Developers blog post here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html) with some relevant details.